# Django DateTimeField ValidationError: value has an invalid format (different question:))

Tags: python, django

The field is simple:

```
timestamp=DateTimeField(primary_key=True)
```

The timestamps are displayed in this format: "June 12, 2021, 2:40 a.m.".

When I try to delete an entry, it gives me this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 616, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 232, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1739, in changelist_view
    response = self.response_action(request, queryset=cl.get_queryset(request))
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1406, in response_action
    queryset = queryset.filter(pk__in=selected)
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 941, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 961, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 968, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1393, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1412, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1347, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1193, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 240, in get_prep_lookup
    rhs_value = self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(rhs_value)
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1406, in get_prep_value
    value = super().get_prep_value(value)
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1266, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1388, in to_python
    raise exceptions.ValidationError(
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“June 12, 2021, 2:40 a.m.” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']
[17/Nov/2021 20:04:01] "POST /admin/micogui/transaction/ HTTP/1.1" 500 162676
```

I've investigated, it's because of the intermediate delete confirmation dialog. When invoking the "delete selected items" action it sends the request with all the entries in correct format (YYYY-MM-DD...), but then after confirmation dialog I see this in the delete_selected_confirmation.html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="{{ action_checkbox_name }}" value="{{ obj.pk|unlocalize }}">
```

After this timestamp is being sent in the format I see on page (June 12, ...) and the code hiccups.

It will require someone from django developers to understand how to fix it best, I'm afraid.

Comment: How are you trying to delete an item?

Comment: Note that the `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS` applies to Django *forms*, not the Django ORM.

Comment: Ticking one entry, then selecting "Delete selected entries" and hitting "Go". Well, here I think it's at least forms, since I see it on the page?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I've investigated, updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

In django 4.2.10 it's not fixed, so (sad but works) I've implemented a hack:

I've overridden delete confirmation template for this model, providing my makeshift obj.timestamp1 in lieu of obj.pk|unlocalize.